# How to texture individual objects

Tags: texturing

This is my first time using blender, I decided to use it because the modelling software I use doesn't have a great texturing system so I imported my model but I when I try to texture an individual object it textures all of the objects as seen here. [image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM

Comment: Generally, until new materials are added, all objects share the same material slot. Thus, when you change the material in that slot, it applies to all the objects. To solve this, add new slots for the different sections using the + button on the right side of the materials panel. You will also have to press the + button underneath the box to add a new material to populate that spot. The new material will not be applied to the objects until you select the wanted sections in edit mode, and (with the material name selected), hit "apply".